# Angular 2 Material Datepicker Value

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2

I want to use [Angular Material Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/component/datepicker) to get a date into my page.
I use this code, but cannot figure out how to access the selected value correctly.

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="myDatepicker">
  <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="myDatepicker"></button>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker #myDatepicker></md-datepicker>
```

I tried the `[value]` field in input but how can I get the date to send it to my backend?
Thanks.

Comment: Put in `input`: `ngModel` if you're using Template forms or `formControl`/`formControlName` for Model Driven..

Comment: I can user the min field correctly, but not the value field. Adding ngModel does not help

Comment: Putting `ngModel` you can see the value of field in component.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can access the datepicker value by using `ngModel`. The `ngModel` needs to be in the `input` tag. See the Plunker [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ucGODHnqlaRi7IgoJNmt?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you very much for the demo. I had tried that before but only then I realiased I had another input field with the name 'date'

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: thanks - I had it right except i had no "name" attribute on the input.
<input name="dob"..> helped

Answer (score 4):

as stated in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api) there are 2 events `(dateChange)` and `(dateInput)` that can be used if you prefer. the `$event` has 3 props, `target` is the `MatDatepickerInput`, `targetElement` for the native HTML Element, and `value` which is the `Date` object.

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerFrom" placeholder="From" 
      (dateChange)="changeFunc($event)"      <<---- you can send $event
      (dateChange)="dateInput($event.value)" <<---- or just $event.value 
>
```

Comment: this seems better cause proceed in one direction

Answer (score 3):

As Nehal said, you can use the **`[(ngModel)]`** binding; I also forgot the `"name"` atribute:

```
  <md-form-field>
    <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="myDateValue" name="myDate"
      [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Select a date">
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning **name** attribute. That did it for me.