# How do i get a value out of Bootstrap's datetimepicker with Angular 4?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get the dates from two bootstrap date time pickers using the `(mouseup)` event of Angular. The template code looks like this:

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<form [formGroup]="leaveCreateForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
        <label for="startDate">Begin datum</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" id="startDate" class="form-control"
               placeholder="01-01-2017" formControlName="startDate"
               (input)="computeLeave()">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
    <label for="endDate">Eind datum</label>
    <input type="datetime-local"  data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="endDate" class="form-control"
           placeholder="02-02-2017" formControlName="endDate"
           (keyup)="computeLeave()">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Berekend</th>
        <th>Beschikbaar</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Wettelijk</td>
        <td>{{leaveRequestedStatutory | number:"1.0-0"}}</td>
        <!--<td>{{leaveRemaining[0] | number:"1.0-0"}}</td>-->
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bovenwettelijk</td>
        <td>{{leaveRequestedNonstatutory | number:"1.0-0"}}</td>
        <!--<td>{{leaveRemaining[1] | number:"1.0-0"}}</td>-->
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Totaal</td>
        <td>{{leaveRequestedTotal | number:"1.0-0"}}</td>
        <!--<td>{{leaveRemainingTotal | number:"1.0-0"}}</td>-->
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Aanvragen</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="onReset()">Reset</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The component method looks like this:

```
  private computeLeave() {
    console.log("computeLeave called..")
    this.leaveStartDate = this.leaveCreateForm.get('startDate').value as Date;
    this.leaveEndDate = this.leaveCreateForm.get('endDate').value as Date;
    console.log("Startdate: " + this.leaveStartDate.toString())
    console.log("EndDate: " + this.leaveEndDate.toString())
    if (this.leaveStartDate !== undefined || this.leaveEndDate !== undefined) {
      this.leaveRequestedTotal = 0;
      this.leaveRequestedStatutory = 0;
      this.leaveRequestedNonstatutory = 0;
    }

    this.leaveRequestedTotal = this.leaveStartDate.getHours() + this.leaveEndDate.getHours();

    this.leaveRequestedStatutory = this.leaveRequestedTotal * 0.8;
    this.leaveRequestedNonstatutory = this.leaveRequestedTotal * 0.2;
  }
```

When I select a date in the datetime picker the retrieved object doesen't contain the selected date, in fact, it doesen't contain anything.

In stackoverflow post[Angular 2 Material Datepicker Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356173/angular-2-material-datepicker-value) They are talking about using [(ngModel)] however i'm using a formGroup object that works with formControlNames so i'm not sure if I can use this approach together with [(ngModel)]. Can someone give me some pointers? I'm rather new to angular.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[(ngModel)]` but if you do I would bind the variable used w/ the reactive forms control i.e.

```
private endDate: Date;
this.leaveCreateForm = fb.group({
   'endDate': this.endDate 
)};

 <input [(ngModel)]="endDate" type="datetime-local"  data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="endDate" class="form-control"
       placeholder="02-02-2017" formControlName="endDate (keyup)="computeLeave()">\
```

Accessed in your component by `this.endDate`.

Otherwise you can also get the value w/o using `[(ngModel)]` by calling the forms `get` function on the form control `value`:

```
this.leaveCreateForm.get('endDate').value;
```

Comment: [(ngModel)]="endDate" <<< this is giving an error and this is already what i' m doing: this.leaveCreateForm.get('endDate').value;. Please see fourth line of my component method excerpt.

Comment: What is the error? And are you using `ngx-boostrap`?

Comment: no i'm using twitter bootstrap. I just found out that it DOES work when I use [(ngModel)] as opposed to something like [(value)]. The problem was the input type which is, datetime-local. When I use datetime or date everything goes well. However I cannot select the date via a dropdown menu when I use datetime. Only with date that dropdownmenu exists. But I need to be able to select the time as well.. Do you happen to know how I can make the dropdown menu appear when i'm using the datetime type? Thank you

Comment: If `datetime-local` doesn't work you can use `date` and `time` types in separate controls to capture date/time. Otherwise you should consider using a library such as `ngx-bootstrap` to safely facilitate this across all browsers since those types are not well supported.